# Finding equation of motion for given Lagrangian with respect to metric

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory, action, variational-calculus

Given the following action in $d$ dimensional $(0,1,...,d-1)$ curved spacetime:
$$ S= \int d^dx\sqrt{-g}\mathscr{L}[\chi,\Phi,g^{\mu\nu}] $$
Where:
$$\mathscr{L}=e^{-2\Phi} \left(-\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}[R-2\Lambda+4g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial_{\nu}\Phi]+g^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\chi\partial_{\nu}\chi+\frac{\beta^2g_{\tau\tau}-\beta_H^2}{(2\pi)^2}\chi^2 \right)$$

Where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the metric $R$ is the ricci scalar relative to this metric, $g_{00}=g_{\tau\tau}=(g^{\tau \tau})^{-1}$,  $\Phi,\chi$ are scalar fields and $\kappa,\beta,\beta_{H},\Lambda$ are constants.

By doing variation by the field $\Phi$ one can obtain the following equation of motion:

$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial\Phi}-\Delta_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}\Phi\right)}\right)=0$$

Where $\Delta_\mu$ is the covariant derivative, more explicitly for our lagrangian this equation reads:

$$R-2\Lambda-4g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial_{\nu}\Phi +4g^{\mu\nu}\Delta_{\mu}\Delta_{\nu}\Phi=2\kappa^2\left(g^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\chi\partial_{\nu}\chi+\frac{\beta^2g_{\tau\tau}-\beta_H^2}{(2\pi)^2}\chi^2\right)$$

Now I want to find another equation of motion, the one with respect to the metric:

$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}\mathscr{L} = 0$$

On the one hand:

$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}} = e^{-2\Phi} \left(-\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}[R_{\mu\nu}+4\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial_{\nu}\Phi]+\partial_{\mu}\chi\partial_{\nu}\chi-\frac{\beta^2g^2_{\tau\tau}}{(2\pi)^2} \delta_{\mu}^{\tau}{\delta}_{\nu}^{\tau}\chi^2 \right) $$

Where I use the following identities:

$$\frac{\partial g_{\tau\tau}}{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}=-g^2_{\tau\tau}\delta_{\mu}^{\tau}{\delta}_{\nu}^{\tau}$$

$$R=g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$$
Where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is Ricci tensor.

On the other hand:

$$-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}\mathscr{L}=e^{-2\Phi} \left(-\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\left[-\frac{1}{2}(R-2\Lambda)g_{\mu\nu}-2d\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial_{\nu}\Phi \right]-\frac{d}{2}\partial_{\mu}\chi\partial_{\nu}\chi-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\beta^2g_{\tau\tau}-\beta_H^2}{(2\pi)^2}g_{\mu \nu}\chi^2 \right) $$

Where this time I used the identity:

$$g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu \nu}=\delta_{\mu}^{\mu}=d$$

Using the equation of motion of $\Phi$ above, we substitute it in $R-2\Lambda$ of our expression which yields eventually:

$$-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}\mathscr{L}= e^{-2\Phi}\left(-\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}[2d\Delta_{\mu}\Delta_{\nu}\Phi]\right) $$

Putting all together

$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}\mathscr{L} = 0 \iff R_{\mu\nu}+4\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial_{\nu}\Phi+2d\Delta_{\mu}\Delta_{\nu}\Phi=2\kappa^2 \left(\partial_\mu\chi\partial_\nu\chi-\frac{\beta^2g^2_{\tau\tau}}{(2\pi)^2} \delta_{\mu}^{\tau}{\delta}_{\nu}^{\tau}\chi^2\right)$$

But according to some papers, the answer should be:

$$R_{\mu\nu}+2\Delta_{\mu}\Delta_{\nu}\Phi=2\kappa^2 \left(\partial_\mu\chi\partial_\nu\chi-\frac{\beta^2g^2_{\tau\tau}}{(2\pi)^2} \delta_{\mu}^{\tau}{\delta}_{\nu}^{\tau}\chi^2\right)$$

Where did I go wrong???

Comment: *Where did I go wrong???* [Should any check-my-work questions be made on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Comment: @Ghoster this is why I posted in the math stack exchange too... this is part of my Ph.D. research and not part of regular homework exercise...

Comment: The accepted answer to that Physics Meta question, by one of our current moderators, says “The level of the question should be utterly irrelevant.” If you cannot resolve the issue yourself, you should seek help from your advisor or fellow researchers.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644459/11127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variation of $R$ with respect to the metric is
$$
\delta g^{ab} R_{ab} + g^{ab} \delta R_{ab} = \delta g^{ab} R_{ab} + \nabla^a \nabla^b (\delta g_{ab}) - g^{cd} \nabla^a \nabla_a (\delta g_{cd}) \\= \delta g^{ab} R_{ab} - \nabla_a \nabla_b (\delta g^{ab}) + g_{cd} \nabla^a \nabla_a (\delta g^{cd}).
$$
(See Appendix E of Wald, for example, for why this is so.) For the typical Einstein-Hilbert action, the last two terms are a total derivative and so they vanish inside the varied action integral.  But in your case, varying the term $e^\Phi R$ gives
$$
e^{\Phi} \left[\delta g^{ab} R_{ab} - \nabla_a \nabla_b (\delta g^{ab}) + g_{cd} \nabla^a \nabla_a (\delta g^{cd}) \right],
$$
and when you integrate the last two terms by parts (to get something of the form $(\cdots) \delta g^{ab}$), you'll get something non-vanishing.

Comment: +1 This answer has utility beyond the scope of the OP’s particular calculation.

Comment: Thank you! you are my savior this change eventually gives the right answer!

Comment: but you have a little mistake:
$$\Delta^{a}\Delta^{b}(\delta g_{ab})-g^{cd}\Delta^{a}\Delta_{a}(\delta g_{cd})=-\Delta_{a}\Delta_{b}(\delta g^{ab})+g_{cd}\Delta^{a}\Delta_{a}(\delta g^{cd})$$

and not equal to
$$-\Delta_{a}\Delta_{b}(\delta g^{ab})-g_{cd}\Delta^{a}\Delta_{a}(\delta g^{cd})$$

Comment: @DanielVainshtein:  No problem. (And typo corrected — thanks!)  If this answered your question, feel free to "accept" it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.  You might want to wait a day or two before doing so, however, in case other answers come in.

Comment: @Ghoster and please remove your minus 1 in the votes if it was you, this is really have utility on the variation of action with dilaton-gravity as you mention

Comment: @DanielVainshtein I didn’t downvote your question, but I think that whoever did downvote it was fully justified in doing so, because check-my-work questions at all levels are off-topic, as I explained in my upvoted comments. The utility of Michael’s answer, which I upvoted, does not change that policy. I also don’t think that you should be asking anyone to change their votes.